Numbers fields in Kendo filter component shows with decimals
I have a Kendo Grid in ASP.NET Core and a kendo filter component that uses the same data source. For number fields, when filtering, the value shows with decimals. For the grid, I found a solution with a custom template:"
   function integerFilter(e) {
    e.element.kendoNumericTextBox({
        spinners: false,
        format: "#",
        decimals: 0
        });
    };


The problem is with the filter component. Has someone had the same issue?
This is my component:
    @(Html.Kendo().Filter<Application.Persons.x>()
    .Name("personsGridFilter")
    .Fields(f =>
    {
                .
                .
        f.Add(p => p.PersonNo).Label("Person No");
        
    })
    )  

The datasource :
   var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    "type": (function () {
        if (kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']) {
            return 'aspnetmvc-ajax';
        } else {
            throw new Error('The kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js script is not included.');
        }
    }
    )(),
        "transport": {
        "read": {
            "url": "@Url.Page("Persons", "All")",
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
            }
        },
        "prefix": ""
    },
    "pageSize": 25,
    "groupPaging": false,
    "total": 0,
    "serverPaging": true,
    "serverSorting": true,
    "serverFiltering": true,
    "serverGrouping": true,
    "serverAggregates": true,
    "schema": {
        "data": "Data",
        "total": "Total",
        "errors": "Errors",
        "model": {
            "id": "PersonId",
                "fields": {
                "PersonId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "PersonNo": {
                    "type": "number",
                        "defaultValue": null
                },
                
            }
        }
    }
})   

I tried to change the type in the data source and also tried to apply the custom template to the component, but I can't figure out how.
Thank you!
enter image description here
